# The max recursion for the coefficient of a polynomial

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, numpy, math

Recently, I came across an interesting counting problem on YouTube posed by [3Blue1Brown-OlympiadLevelCounting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric). The problem is to find the number of subsets of the set {1, 2, ..., 2000} whose elements' sum is divisible by five. Grant Sanderson presented a beautiful solution, but he also discussed how cumbersome the algorithm could become if implemented on computers to solve the problem efficiently.

However, there is beauty in using integer partitions to solve this problem, thanks to the work of the Euler. The solution is the sum of the [distinct partitions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) of all multiples of 5 less than or equal to 2000 something similar to what I had [posted on MathstackExchange years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4363800/how-does-this-algorithm-that-multiplies-1-x1-x21-x31-x4/4363954#4363954), where the comment by use "dxiv" was the key to this code.

Undoubtedly, Grant Sanderson's solution is elegant as it does not require a computer and can be found without lengthy calculations.

My code is:

```py
import numpy as np

def p(k):
    if k == 1:
        return np.array([1, 1])
    else:
        q = p(k - 1)
    return add(q, np.append(np.zeros(k, int), q))


def add(u, v):
    u = np.append(u, np.zeros(len(v) - len(u), int))
    return np.add(u, v)


def test(n):
    a = 1 << n
    b = 1 << (n//5)
    b *= 4
    return (a+b)//5


n = 1000      
generating_function = sum(p(n)[0:-1:5])+1
grant_sanderson = test(n)
print(generating_function)
print(grant_sanderson)
print(generating_function == grant_sanderson)
```

My difficulty is when `n` is a large number. Also, these numbers are too large that I have to use `gmpy2` this is a graph that shows that arrays are symmetric about `n//2`:

[image: a graph]

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\patil\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Theorie-der-Zahlen\Distinct partitions\distinctParitions-gmp2\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    generating_function = sum(p(n)[0:-1:5])+1
                              ^^^^
  File "c:\Users\patil\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Theorie-der-Zahlen\Distinct partitions\distinctParitions-gmp2\generatingfunction.py", line 8, in p
    q = p(k - 1)
        ^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\patil\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Theorie-der-Zahlen\Distinct partitions\distinctParitions-gmp2\generatingfunction.py", line 8, in p
    q = p(k - 1)
        ^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\patil\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Theorie-der-Zahlen\Distinct partitions\distinctParitions-gmp2\generatingfunction.py", line 8, in p
    q = p(k - 1)
        ^^^^^^^^
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

This code can show how things quickly go out of hands:

```py
import gmpy2

def q(n):
    Q = [gmpy2.mpz(0)] * (n+1)
    Q[0] = gmpy2.mpz(1)
    for k in range(1, n):
        for i in range(n, k-1, -1):
            Q[i] += Q[i-k]
    return Q[n] + 1
```

Comment: Have you debugged if your recursion works as expected?

Comment: `p` is recursive.  Did you expect it to go this many times?  If not, then your test to stop recursing is not working.  I'd suggest adding some diagnostic prints, and a 'hard' stop, to determine exactly what's going on.

Comment: If you have verified the recursion is working as expected, you can increase the recursion limit (sys.setrecursionlimit(N)). You can also try the decorator @functools.lru_cache, which might help with memoization.

Comment: @MrSmith42, while the solution works well for small numbers, things start to fall out of hand when n becomes large, causing the code to throw unpredictably or unmanageable numbers and had to use `gmpy2`

Comment: Surely the recursion for function `p` is not needed, and you can do a simple `for`-loop instead? `def p(n): q=np.array([1, 1]); for k in range(n): add(q, np.append(np.zeros(k, int), q)); return q`

Comment: Thank you, Stef and stressed, for your suggestions, but unfortunately, they did not work.

stressed: Although `setrecursionlimit()` doesn't raise a recursion error, it still presents issues with large values.
stef: I might have misunderstood your comment, but unfortunately, but this couldn't help me figure out the problem.

Comment: Don't use recursion when you expect many iterations, like 1000 of them. Use a loop instead. (and cache your intermediary results: if you ask for `p(1000)`, then by definition you're also asking for `p(999)` through `p(1)`. Save those values, and look them up instead of recomputing them. Only compute values you haven't already computed before)

Comment: Thank for the edits, @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans also, Your comment++ it helps

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @mkrieger1 [This code](https://linkode.org/#t6E1nyQd8ZQ223qOGeLG14) is correct but can't handle large values of `n`
Although I was interested in finding the solution to [question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric) but now I'm into fixing the code than finding the solution of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative method would be to count combinations of sums that reach each of the 5 modulo values (0,1,2,3,4). Hold these counts in a list and increase them progressively. At the end, take the count for the zero modulo to get the number of sets that add up to a multiple of 5:

```
def sumDiv5Count(numbers):
    modCounts = [0]*5
    for n in numbers:
        modCounts = [c+modCounts[(i-n)%5] for i,c in enumerate(modCounts)]
        modCounts[n%5] += 1        
    return modCounts[0]
```

Each number's modulo 5 combines with the 5 possible moduli to add more ways to produce 5 distinct resulting modulo values.

For example 13%5 -> 3,

- ways to produce 0 are added to ways to produce 0+3 --> slot 3
- ways to produce 1 are added to ways to produce 1+3 --> slot 4
- ways to produce 2 are added to ways to produce 2+3 --> slot 0  (2+3)%5 = 0
- ways to produce 3 are added to ways to produce 3+3 --> slot 1  (3+3)%5 = 1
- ways to produce 4 are added to ways to produce 4+3 --> slot 2  (4+3)%5 = 2
- and there is one more way to produce 3 by itself

output:

```
print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,10)))
# 103

print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,50)))
# 112589990684671

print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,100)))
# 126765060022822940149670739967

print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,500)))
# 327339060789614187001318969682759915221664204604306478948329136809613379640467455488327009232590415715088668412756007101428785894679831065931534041087

print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,1000)))
# 1071508607186267320948425049060001810561404811705533607443750388370351051124936122493198378815695858127594672917553146825187145285692314043598457757469857480393456777482423098542107460506237114187795418215304647498358194126739876755916554395250481509160715757985439053702508024174143636196837700927487

print(sumDiv5Count(range(1,2001)))
# 22962613905485090484656664023553639680446354041773904009552854736515325227847406277133189726330125398368919292779749255468942379217261106628518627123333063707825997829062456000137755829648008974285785398012697248956323092729277672789463405208093270794180999311632479761788925921124662329907232844394066536268833781796891701120475896961582811780186955300085800543341325166104401626447256258352253576663441319799079283625404355971680808431970636650308177886780418384110991556717934409897816293912852988275811422719154702569434391547265221166310540389294622648560061463880851178273858239474974548427800575
```

One nice thing about this approach is that it could easily be turned into a generator that yields the count progressively as it goes through the numbers.  It is also not dependent on the numbers being in a sequence or even distinct. Performance is good (a few milliseconds) given that it's an O(n) process.

Comment: This is elegant, and this does answer the [solution](https://linkode.org/#eeTEZXpmLoh26MoJpyaO37) of the [problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOXCLR3Wric)

Comment: Thank you for providing a solution to my question. Although it didn't directly solve my code issue, I would like to accept it as my answer because I believe it is ingenious yet simple, unlike my complicated approach.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't throw recursion error!
Changes made to the original code:

- `sys.setrecursionlimit(2500)`
- Don't know why, but `gmpy2` was throwing wrong numbers. so used `decimal.Decimal` instead

```py
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2500)

def p(k):
    if k == 1:
        return [Decimal(1), Decimal(1)]
    else:
        q = p(k - 1)
        return add(q, [Decimal(0)] * k + q)


def add(u, v):
    u = u + [Decimal(0)] * (len(v) - len(u))
    return [x + y for x, y in zip(u, v)]




def test(n):
    getcontext().prec = n+10  
    a = Decimal(1 << n)
    b = Decimal(1 << (n//5))
    b *= Decimal(4)
    result = (a+b)/Decimal(5)
    return Decimal(result)  

n = 2000
generating_function = sum(p(n)[0:-1:5])+1
print(generating_function)
```